# openvpn setup ping/routing fail

Tags: ubuntu, routing, openvpn, ping

My problem is that after setting up VPN on a virtual machine (Ubuntu Linux) with that has an IP I cant ping anyone at all over the tun interface from the client. VPN Connection is however successful.
*I would be eternally grateful for any help*. I have looked in google, obviously without success, because of the varying scenarios that could cause this problem.

Here are the setup details :

- Network 192.168.0.0 with netmask 255.255.255.0 with default gateway 192.168.0.1
- Network runs off a Linksys router , I also have a dyndns account. And have opened port       1194, so that the router forwards everything to 192.168.0.106 for this port.
- Openvpn server IP 192.168.0.106 with port 1194 open.
- Routing table entry in router:

  - Destination : 192.168.10.0 (IP Pool for OpenVpn)
  - Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
  - Gateway 192.168.0.106

Openvpn server.conf :

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

;dev tap
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert homesrv.crt
key homesrv.key  # This file should be kept secret

dh dh1024.pem

server 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

;server-bridge

push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

;learn-address ./script

;push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"

;client-to-client

;duplicate-cn

keepalive 10 120

;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

comp-lzo

max-clients 2

;user nobody
;group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

verb 5
mute 20
```

Comment: I have almost the same config except that l have pushed an existing DNS server. What's the client's DNS setting?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Does the dns setting of the client play a role? I thought since openvpn controlls the tun interface on the client it would take care of the dns.

Comment: @joeqwerty the problem is I cannot ping anybody on the network I am trying to connect to once it is connected. Thus not achieving the goal of said vpn in the first place. I suspect it has to do with a routing problem, perhaps on the router side, so that the traffic is not redirected to 192.168.0.106